# php ajax multiple requests

Tags: php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I been learning php and ajax from w3schools but I have come across a simply question for which I cant find an answer to.

To request something from a php file I use a xmlhttpRequest object and specify the url (of that php file). Does this mean one php file for one request only? Let's say on a webpage there are a user log-in box and a comment box, I would need two php files to take the requests? I always thought the server side will have one main file that handle all the requests, each request from client will have a ID to specify what the request is and send back the necessary data to client. So what is the right?

I read a lot of material online, but everything is just basic example with just one request and one response.

Comment: w3schools often has wrong information. Be very careful taking it at face value. Especially when you're learning (and then even as a pro) it's much better to use a Javascript framework such as jQuery http://jquery.com rather than trying to code straight javascript.  Finally there is no right answer to your question. You can have multiple files or you can have a single file with conditional logic to do different things depending on the request.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I am planning to learn it elsewhere once I get the basic down, it's just that w3school simplify everything so I can learn quicker. Get the basic structure down then start coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same file for multiple requests. You can supply parameters along with the AJAX request, either by including them in the URL after `?` (they'll be available in `$_GET` and `$_REQUEST`) or by using the `POST` method and sending them as form data (they'll be available in `$_POST` and `$_REQUEST`). You can use the Javascript FormData API to encode this properly; see the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData). Using the jQuery library can simplify all of this.

One of the parameters can then be a command or operation code, and the script can take different actions based on this.